# List of an element's events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to find all of the events for a element in javascript? or a way to unbind all events from a element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not way to do that directly using javascript.

Jquery has a couple of functions to keep track of that data.

One "pure" way to do that is to change the addEventListener/attachEvent function through prototyping (search about javascript prototype stuff, not the framework).

Or if you have a custom function to hadle adding/removing events you can tune it.

Well, that's it.

Comment: I am using a custom function to addEvents (handle ie etc). is there a way to save all of the events (names and functions) added to a element?

Comment: Hi errorhandler, I suspect that you were using a custom function to handle IE addEvent. Well, I think you can tune this function, adding to a global var/object with the event data - target element, target event, and callback function, and then in this custom var/object, add some functions to retrieve the needed data.

Answer (score 3):

Of course !
Take a look at this to bind/unbind events
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/
and use this jQuery code fragment to get all the events bound to an element in the form of a hashset of keypairs "eventname/function delegate"

```
jQuery(elem).data('events');
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without jQuery?

Comment: Well, afaik everything's needed is to include the jQuery API. That code chunk should work also for events not directly bound by jQuery.

Comment: The code of this answer works only up to jQuery 1.7.2. Starting from jQuery 1.8 you have to use this instead: `$._data(elem, 'events')`. Also note it's supposed to be used only internally, so you should use it for debugging purposes only, and it's not future-proof.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want ot use jQuery, a quick and dirty way (and there's bound to be a better one) would be to loop through the element's parameters and check for functions that begin with 'on' (onclick etc).

```
var el = document.getElementById('elementid') ;
el.onclick = function(e) { console.log('Clicked!') ; } ; // Attached test event.
if(typeof(el)=='object') {
   for(var i in el) {
      if(i.substr(0,2) == 'on' && typeof(el[i])=='function') {
         el[i] = function() {} ; // Unbind with null function.
      }
   }
}
```