# Find events available for element

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

[jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) asks about how to list event handlers registered with an object.

How do I list what events are available for an element I can add an event handler to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910123/list-of-an-elements-events ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you do that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried adding an event handler responding to an input element being clicked, but I found that didn't really meet my needs because I need to handle the user submitting a file they've chosen, rather than bringing up the file selection interface. So I'm trying to work out what event would be more suitable.

Comment: Than you need to use `event.stopPropagation()` on the clicked element (that way the click won't propagate to the (I suppose) parent element that calls the file select interface.)